# How to write this Subscript for Lagrangian Minimization Equation in Beamer

Tags: beamer, subscripts

So I want an \alpha below the word 'minimise' as in [this](http://web.media.mit.edu/~gordonw/CompressiveLightFieldPhotography/CompressiveLightFieldPhotography.pdf) paper in equation 5 and 6.  [image: image :]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You could use

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\minimize}{minimize}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A slide}
\[\minimize_{\{\alpha\}} \|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{i}}-\boldsymbol{\Phi\mathcal{D}\alpha}\|_2
+\lambda \|\boldsymbol{\alpha}\|_1\]
or 
$\displaystyle\minimize_{\{\alpha\}} \|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{i}}-\boldsymbol{\Phi\mathcal{D}\alpha}\|_2
+\lambda \|\boldsymbol{\alpha}\|_1$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that none of this is specific to beamer.

Comment: Nice answer! One tiny comment: you don't need `\usepackage{amsmath}`, beamer already loads it.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks! That's correct. (I still want to keep it because I mention that this is not specific to beamer.)

Comment: Oh, right! Then it makes sense to keep it